# Javascript - WebSocket client not receiving onmessage event when server sends large response

Tags: javascript, .net, websocket

I`m creating .net websocket server based on TcpClient and NetworkStream communicating with Javascript client. After handshake, client asks for server to perform specific actions and server generates response - so far it was short JSON strings being sent back to the client - and it works ok.

After I got requirement to send larger string responses (namely, base64 encoded images with 200k and more bytes), client stopped receiving responses and there is no onmessage event being fired. If I switch and send short json - it works again fine.

When I send large data:

[image: When sending large data]

When I send simple data:

[image: When sending simple data]

Client side I stripped down the code from everything unrelated (behavior remained the same)

```
try{
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8282");
    ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
}
catch(err){
    debugger;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Not Connected! " + err;         
};
ws.onopen = function () {
    var jsonRequest = '{"action" : "START_STREAM","timeout"  : 20}';
    ws.send("START_STREAM");
};
```

On the server side, I isolated the code after the response is generated (plain string with base64 encoded image, which I tested and decodes correctly):

```
 Byte[] frame = CreateFrameFromString(serverResponse);
 networkStream.Write(frame, 0, frame.Count());
 networkStream.Flush();
 clientSocket.Close();
 clientSocket = ServerListener.AcceptTcpClient();
 networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
```

Code for initing server thread:

```
 ServerListener.Start();
 clientSocket = ServerListener.AcceptTcpClient();
 NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
 while (true)
    {
     if (!networkStream.DataAvailable)
  ...regular loop/server stuff/handshake etc.
```

Method CreateFrameFromString is bellow. Opcode is tested with values 0-10 and in all cases the behavior was the same - no response caught on client side.

```
 private static byte[] CreateFrameFromString(string message, Opcode opcode = Opcode.Text)
    {
        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        byte[] frame;

        if (payload.Length < 126)
        {
            frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
            frame[1] = (byte)payload.Length;
            Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 2, payload.Length);
        }
        else if (payload.Length >= 126 && payload.Length <= 65535)
        {
            frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length option*/ + 2 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
            frame[1] = 126;
            frame[2] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[3] = (byte)(payload.Length & 255);
            Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 4, payload.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            frame = new byte[1 /*op code*/ + 1 /*payload length option*/ + 8 /*payload length*/ + payload.Length /*payload bytes*/];
            frame[1] = 127; // <-- Indicates that payload length is in following 8 bytes.
            frame[2] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 56) & 255);
            frame[3] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 48) & 255);
            frame[4] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 40) & 255);
            frame[5] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 32) & 255);
            frame[6] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 24) & 255);
            frame[7] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 16) & 255);
            frame[8] = (byte)((payload.Length >> 8) & 255);
            frame[9] = (byte)(payload.Length & 255);
            Array.Copy(payload, 0, frame, 10, payload.Length);
        }

        frame[0] = (byte)((byte)opcode | 0x80 /*FIN bit*/);

        return frame;
    }
```

Am I missing something - protocol/buffer size/etc.? While testing I noticed that I could send response with up to 4250 chars with the above setup, with no modifications. Once I`ve hit around that number, response started disapearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of troubleshooting, it turned out that I had to send data in packages, not as a whole piece. I split the response in chunks (50000 chars) and sent them 1 by 1, while on client side I was picking up the pieces in onmessage event. After all response chunks were sent, I closed the session - which on client side triggered creation of the image from base64 stream.